# aws-cli usage questions go....?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, migration, stackexchange

I *suppose* if you're using an API to run the CLI, that could be asked in Stackoverflow, but might not be best.

I don't have the question handy, but saw that a question was closed as off topic because it related to aws-cli itself, which isn't a Linux distro.

Maybe group all VPS stuff into one stack?

[this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/267478/17056) comment:

> Flagged to close because the AWS command line tools are not platform
>   specific, nor are any of the problems mentioned here. – Evan Carroll
>   Apr 22 '16 at 16:16

This question:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336179/can-i-send-e-mails-from-amazon

will be closed.  It's not really a programming question...

makes me wonder.  migrate to where?

Comment: I don't understand your question, specifically the bit at the end about VPS stuff into one stack?

Comment: **stack**exchange ;)

Comment: There's always [su]

Comment: The first question, AWS-cli, while off topic for U&L, is perfect for [Web Applicataions](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) under the `/amazon-ec2` tag. The email question is now, for me, a 404 page, so I can only guess, but it might have been on topic there too. Or, if it was from a web master point of view, then it might have fit on [Pro Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), which also deals with AWS hosting.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver thanks, didn't realize that web applications questions could be also CLI.

Comment: I think that some questions regarding the AWS CLI would fit well here.  For example, if you were calling AWS CLI commands from a Bash or KSH script or needed help with a one liner.